# Média móvel no R

Tags: r

Preciso fazer uma média móvel simples de 7 dias no R, estou utilizando a função `rollmean` do pacote `zoo`, mas os valores que estão sendo retornados estão incorretos.

Exemplo:

```
library(zoo)

teste <- sample(1:50)
mean <- rollmean(teste, 7, align = "right")
teste <- cbind(teste, mean)
```

Resultado:

```
  teste     mean
  42     27.42857
  21     22.85714
  11     25.57143
  48     29.85714
  33     34.85714
  29     36.28571
  8      34.57143
  10     29.28571
  40     25.85714
  41     26.85714
```

No último valor, que retornou 26.85714, deveria retornar 25.57143, que seria a média dos 7 dias anteriores (40, 10, 8, 29, 33, 48, 11). O que está acontecendo?

Obs.: sei que a função `sample` gera valores aleatórios e que sua execução não resultará nos mesmos valores apresentados no exemplo.

Comment: Pode usar `set.seed()` para tornar a geração de dados aleatórios reproduzível.

Comment: Você deve usar o set.seed(). Por favor, leia o manual de boas práticas aqui do R. Os exemplos precisam ser reproduzíveis para podermos analisar. Para isso, é importante especificar o seed quando você usa dados aleatórios. Seu uso é bem simples, basta especificar um número qualquer por exemplo `set.seed(123)`. Nessa sua pergunta não foi crucial, mas pode haver outras que você acabará sem resposta só pq não foi reproduzível.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os valores estão corretos, o problema está no comportamento do R com dois vetores de tamanho diferente. A média móvel precisa de 7 valores para ser computada, então o R só começa a análise no 7 ponto e as primeiras 6 observações são descartadas. O vetor `mean` então tem 6 elementos a menos que o vetor `teste`.

Para vetores de tamanho diferente o comportamento padrão do R é repetir o vetor menor até ele ficar do mesmo tamanho do maior.

```r
# comportamento do R

x <- 1:2
y <- 1:3

x + y
#> Warning in x + y: comprimento do objeto maior não é múltiplo do comprimento do
#> objeto menor
#> [1] 2 4 4

# soma de 1 + 1, 2 + 2 e 3 + 1, porque o vetor menos é repetido
```

Por isso seu ultimo valor de média na tabela não é a média do ultimo valor e sim de algum valor anterior que foi repetido, se for olhar na tabela que você calculou você vai ver que os ultimos numeros são repetidos do primeiros. Para consertar isso é só botar `NA` nos primeiros valores da tabela ou desconsiderá-los, porque ali a média não é calculada.

```r
library(zoo)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
set.seed(3)

#original
teste <- sample(1:50)
mean <- rollmean(teste, 7, align = "right")
teste_tabela <- cbind(teste, mean)
#> Warning in cbind(teste, mean): number of rows of result is not a multiple of
#> vector length (arg 2)

mean(teste_tabela[44:50, 1]) == mean(teste_tabela[50,2])
#> [1] FALSE

#corrigido para os primeiros 6 valores
teste_tabela <- cbind(teste, c(rep(NA, 6), mean))

mean(teste_tabela[44:50, 1]) == mean(teste_tabela[50,2]) 
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Ao calcular médias móveis o resultado terá um comprimento menor ao dos dados originais:

```
library(zoo)

set.seed(42)
teste <- sample(1:50)
mean <- rollmean(teste, 7, align = "right")

> length(teste)
[1] 50
> length(mean)
[1] 44
```

Ao unir os dois vetores, o menor (das médias móveis) será reciclado (i.e. vai voltar ao início e preencher os espaços "faltantes"):

```
> uniao <- cbind(teste, mean)
Warning message:
In cbind(teste, mean) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
> head(uniao)
    teste     mean
[1,]    46 33.85714
[2,]    50 28.14286
[3,]    14 25.00000
[4,]    40 27.14286
[5,]    30 24.14286
[6,]    24 25.71429
> tail(uniao)
      teste     mean
[45,]    20 33.85714
[46,]    39 28.14286
[47,]     9 25.00000
[48,]     2 27.14286
[49,]    43 24.14286
[50,]     8 25.71429
```

Ao unir os dois, precisa considerar a diferença e incluir NAs de acordo com o alinhamento:

```
uniao <- cbind(teste,
              c(rep(NA, length(teste)-length(mean)), mean)) # NAs no início porque usou align = "right"
```

Se usar `align = "left"`, pode alterar o comprimento de `mean`; NAs serão introduzidos no final:

```
teste <- sample(1:50)
mean <- rollmean(teste, 7, align = "left")

length(mean) <- length(teste)

> tail(cbind(teste, mean), 10)
      teste     mean
[41,]    30 27.28571
[42,]    23 23.28571
[43,]    17 26.42857
[44,]    44 28.57143
[45,]    50       NA
[46,]     6       NA
[47,]    21       NA
[48,]     2       NA
[49,]    45       NA
[50,]    32       NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Além das respostas que já foram dadas, [(1)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/451451/82237) e [(2)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/451450/82237), a minha resposta é mais simples (mas não explica a razão do erro da questão) porque usa

1. A função `rollmeanr` que por defeito alinha as médias à direita;
2. O argumento `fill = NA` precisamente para não se obter um vetor menor que o vetor de entrada;
3. Em conjunto, os dois pontos acima evitam o erro, daí esta resposta não o explicar.

O código fica então assim:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- sample(1:50)
m <- zoo::rollmeanr(x, k = 7, fill = NA)

teste_tabela <- cbind(x, m)
mean(teste_tabela[44:50, 1]) == teste_tabela[50,2] 
#[1] TRUE
```